# Chrome is wrong displaying border radius if is one of side disabled

Tags: css, google-chrome, border

I have problem with displaying border-radius in Google Chrome.

Radius is wrongly appearing when is border rule defined globaly for all sides and one/more of side/s is/are disabled. 
It simply doesnt apply this radius on corner.

On Safari or Edge works normally.
[image: example]

HTML

```
<div class="box">
  Normal
</div>
<div class="box notop">
  No TOP
</div>
```

CSS

```
.box {
    border: 6px solid red;
    border-radius: 2px;
    padding: 15px;
    margin: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
}
.notop {
    border-top: none;
}
```

Look at this fiddle -> https://jsfiddle.net/ter6cLpo/

Im missing something? Thanks for help.

Comment: Your fiddle is working for me in Chrome 61.0.xxx

Comment: works fine for me in chrome

Comment: Weird, try this fiddle, the border-radius at end is not same as on start of pagination. https://jsfiddle.net/t7a1vhtk/1/

Comment: Try to add `-webkit-` prefix to your styles. By the way, I have Chrome Version 61.0.3163.100 (Official Build) (64-bit), and your code works just fine.

Comment: Same here on Chromium 57.0.2987.98 (the repository version in Debian).